# Daily budget on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for a daily budget alert on my AWS usage, for example in case I leave an EC2 instance running or if a user requests too many one-time passcodes on SNS. I already use monthly budget alarms, and CloudWatch alarms attached to EC2 instances.

In 2020 [AWS announced daily granularity on Budgets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/launch-daily-cost-and-usage-budgets/) for some customers:

> Daily budget granularity is already available to Savings Plans and Reservation budget users.

On [AWS Budgets](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/budgets/overview), I do not have the option to create a daily budget. I only see "Zero-spend budget", "Monthly budget" and "Daily Savings Plan Coverage Budget".

Does AWS offer daily budget alarms for the general user?

Comment: I've never heard of one. You could try a monthly budget with forecast numbers, that might reflect any resources left turned on. You could also try a more of an enforcement approach, use AWS Instance Scheduler to turn servers off, use lambda functions to turn anything else regularly used off, Cloudwatch alerts for SNS, etc.

Comment: Actually, a monthly budget with a daily period seems to do what I want and I get an email each day that I exceed a threshold. I also have a graph showing spend per day.

Comment: Great. Suggest you provide an answer below to help out anyone who has the problem in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a budget with a daily period. Go to the budget page and click on "Create a budget" (or go directly [here](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1&skipRegion=true#/budgets/create)), then for budget type choose "Customized" and "Cost budget":

[image: choose budget type]

In the next page, choose "Daily" as the period:

[image: choose period]

After selecting and confirming the other choices, you will see this in the page for your budget:

[image: daily budget result]

and also a nice graph with a budget history:

[image: daily budget history]